# Estimate problem related to the asymptotic expension of Wallis integral

Tags: asymptotics, laplace-method

In the books [Analytic combinatorics](https://ac.cs.princeton.edu/home/AC.pdf), the authors write (p. 757, eq (36)), with $k_n=n^{1/10}$, that

\begin{align*}
 I^{(1)}_{n}:&=\int_{-k_{n}/\sqrt{n}}^{k_{n}/\sqrt{n}}\cos^n(x)\ dx\\
 &=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\int_{-k_{n}}^{k_{n}}e^{-w^2/2}\exp\left(\mathcal{O}(n^{-1}w^{4})\right)\ dw\\
 &=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\int_{-k_{n}}^{k_{n}}e^{-w^2/2}\left(1+\mathcal{O}(n^{-1}w^{4})\right)\ dw\\
 &=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\int_{-k_{n}}^{k_{n}}e^{-w^2/2}\ dw+\mathcal{O}(n^{-3/5}).\\
\end{align*}
I have a problem with the last equality where it seems to me that the last estimate should be $\mathcal{O}(n^{-3/2})$ instead of $\mathcal{O}(n^{-3/5})$ as $w^4 e^{-w^2}$ is integrable over $\mathbb{R}$. It seems that I miss something, but I could not find out what it is...

Thanks

Comment: You are completely right. You can report the error here: https://ac.cs.princeton.edu/errata/errata.php It has not been reported yet.